# Ruby: Calculate time difference between 2 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I want to calculate the difference between 2 times.
start_time: 22:00 (Rails interprets this as 2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100)
second_time: 02:00 (Rails interprets this as 2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100). The second time is 4 hours later, so in the next day. Is there a way to calculate this difference?

I can not simply do this: second_time - first_time, because this gives me a difference of 22 hours instead of 4 hours.

Edit:
**Some background information:**
A job is starting at 22:00 and ending the next day at 02:00. Because i fill in the form of this job only times, this times for the above 2 values are 2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100 and 2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100. I don't want the user to fill in the time including the date. The real difference between the times should be 4 hours.

So what i actually want is calculate the difference between 22:00 and 02:00 (in the next day).

Comment: How can `2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100` be within the day after `2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100`? They are the same days.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't understand why you think it should return 4 hours or why it does return 22 hours. 20 hours would be correct for your example:

```
require 'time'

a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100')
b = Time.parse('2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100')

a - b
#=> 72000.0 # difference in seconds

(a - b) / 3600
#=> 20.0  # difference in hours
```

---

**Update**: It seems like you are dealing only with the time portion and not with the actual date. And I assume the maximum difference you will have to deal with is 24 hours:

```
def time_difference(time_a, time_b)
  difference = time_b - time_a

  if difference > 0
    difference
  else
    24 * 3600 + difference 
  end
end

a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100')
b = Time.parse('2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100')
time_difference(a, b) / 3600
# => 4 # hours

a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100')
b = Time.parse('2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100')
time_difference(a, b) / 3600
# => 20 # hours
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, i've added some background information in my post and thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MattDice: I updated my answer. I hope I understood your requirements correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I did a nice method to deal with it:

```
def time(start,ending)
  if start != ending
    medidas=["year","month","day","hour","minute","second"]
    array=[1970,1,1,0,0,0]
    text = ""
    Time.at(ending-start).utc.to_a.take(6).reverse.each_with_index do |k,i|
      text = "#{text} #{I18n.translate medidas[i].to_sym, count: k-array[i]}"
    end
    text = text.strip.squish
    pos = text.rindex(" ",(text.rindex(" ")-1))
    unless pos.nil?
      text = text.insert(pos," and")
    end
    text = text.strip.squish #This shouldn't be needed but just in case
  else
    "0 seconds"
  end
end
```

Then in config/locales/en.yml I added:

```
en:
 año:
    zero: ''
    one: '1 year'
    other: '%{count} years'
 mes:
    zero: ''
    one: '1 month'
    other: '%{count} months'
 dia:
    zero: ''
    one: '1 day'
    other: '%{count} days'
 hora:
    zero: ''
    one: '1 hour'
    other: '%{count} hours'
 minuto:
    zero: ''
    one: '1 minute'
    other: '%{count} minutes'
 segundo:
    zero: ''
    one: '1 second'
    other: '%{count} seconds'
```

So for example when you call:

```
start = Time.now
ending = start + (60*60)

time(start,ending)
=> "1 hour"

ending = start + (60*60*28)
time(start,ending)
=> "1 day and 4 hours"

ending = start + (53*60*5874)
time(start,ending)
=> "7 months 4 days 4 hours and 42 minutes"
```

Hope it's useful

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it thusly (before adding data checks), in an attempt to make it self-documenting:

```
require 'time'

DT_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24*60*60

def hours_elapsed(start_str, finish_str)
  start  = DateTime.strptime(start_str,  DT_FMT).to_time
  finish = DateTime.strptime(finish_str, DT_FMT).to_time
  finish = same_time_tomorrow(finish) if finish < start
  (finish-start)/3600
end

def same_time_tomorrow(time)
  time + SECONDS_PER_DAY
end

hours_elapsed '2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100',
              '2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100'
  #=>  4.0
hours_elapsed '2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100',
              '2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100'
  #=> 20.0
```

It may be better for the arguments of `hours_elapsed` to be strings containing hours and minutes only, in which case we might rename the method as well. `time_elapsed("18:00", "2:30")` is an example of how this method might be invoked.

```
MINUTES_PER_DAY = 24*60

def time_elapsed(start_str, finish_str)
  start_mins = time_str_to_minutes(start_str)  
  finish_mins = time_str_to_minutes(finish_str)
  finish_mins += MINUTES_PER_DAY if
    finish_mins < start_mins
  (finish_mins-start_mins).divmod(60)
end

def time_str_to_minutes(str)
  hrs, mins = str.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  60 * hrs + mins
end

time_elapsed("8:00", "17:30")
  #=> [9, 30] 
time_elapsed("18:00", "2:30")
  #=> [8, 30]
```

Comment: would please help me out to find out how can I use your solution but only take the `hour`& `min` and not the whole date. Because when `hours_elapsed '2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100', '2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100'` would give 4 `hours_elapsed '2015-12-21 22:00:00 +0100', '2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100'` would give `220.0` and I'm only need the hours and min. I would appreciate a lot if you would do that.

Comment: @Rubioli, please see my edit. Have I answered your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot @CarySwoveland. You are the best :) I have a quick question that might sound stupid. Why array as output and not like `9:30`? :)

Comment: You could do that (`[9,30].join(':')`). Whether you should depends on how the result is to be used subsequently in the program. If separate values for hours and minutes are wanted returning an array would make more sense (rather than `h,m = "9:30".split(":").map(&:to_i)`).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot @CarySwoveland