# How to fetch current time stamp in Appium ruby client lib

Tags: rubygems, appium

I am trying to fetch current timestamp and the print difference between two

**Scenario**

```
startTime= current time stamp 
//Do some action 
StopTime= Current time stamp 
puts (stopTime - startTime)
```

**What I tried:**

```
startTime = $driver.device_time
sleep (5)
stopTime = $driver.device_time
puts (stopTime-startTime)
```

**Error I am facing:**

$driver.device_time returns 2019-01-08T12:35:25+05:30
    in string format so stopTime-startTime does not work

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related to this question. Try going through this?

[Ruby: Calculate time difference between 2 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548355/ruby-calculate-time-difference-between-2-times)

You can probably seperate the code as per your feature design.