# Get difference between 2 hours

Tags: ruby, difference

In my application I need to get `hour` & `min` from *something* and find its time difference to current UTC time.

Basically, I'm trying to get the time difference between 2 different *times/hours(&min)*.

```
my_time = '2019-02-24 16:52' # This I get from my application
a = DateTime.parse(my_time).strftime('%H:%M')
=> '16:52'

b = Time.utc(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day, Time.now.hour, Time.now.min).strftime('%H:%M')
=> '15:52'
```

Optimal way would to just do, but gives error since they are *of course* `string`:

```
time_difference = a - b  # out would be +1
```

I have also tried the answer in the *duplicated question*, but it takes the date in considration.

For instance:

```
a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100')
b = Time.parse('2015-11-31 22:00:00 +0100')
c = time_difference(a, b) / 3600
```

would become `-676.0` and not `4`

Comment: If you want to do calculations on the times, why convert them back to strings before trying it?

Comment: They got converted to string when use `.strftime('%H:%M')` to get the `hour` & `min` plus, + `my_time` is already a `string` when I get it. Thanks for your edit btw @jonrsharpe

Comment: Yes, I know that - my question is *why do you do that*? If you actually want times, for doing calculations, why create strings?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `my_time` is already a string when I *get* it and I thought I need to do `.strftime('%H:%M')` in order to get hours and min from them. Otherwise I have less clues about exactly how to do it. Btw for `my_time` I also have it in unix timestamp for doing something like: `Time.at(1550229840)`  if that could help, but when I do `Time.at(1550229840) - Time.utc`, I get `TypeError: expected numeric`

Comment: I understand why you're *parsing* it, from the string to a datetime, with `DateTime.parse(my_time)`. My point is: if you want to do calculations with it, *don't format it back to a string*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: Calculate time difference between 2 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548355/ruby-calculate-time-difference-between-2-times)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just tried the answer the in *duplicated marked* answer, and it doesn't work. `a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100')
b = Time.parse('2015-11-31 02:00:00 +0100')
time_difference(a, b) / 3600` would output `-676.0` and not `4`

Comment: @zeitnot I just tried the answer and it doesn't only hours and min that I mentioned and it take the whole date. for instance: `a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 22:00:00 +0100') b = Time.parse('2015-11-31 02:00:00 +0100') time_difference(a, b) / 3600` would output `-676.0` and not `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm getting completely the point, but maybe this could work for you:

Given the times, without converting to string.

```
my_time = '2019-02-24 16:52'
a = Time.parse(my_time)
b = Time.utc(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day, Time.now.hour, Time.now.min)
```

With Ruby 2.6.1 ([**Object#then**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-then)):

```
[ ( Time.parse(a.to_s.split[1]) - Time.parse(b.to_s.split[1]) ) / 3600 ].then { |delta| delta[0] < 0 ? 24 + delta[0] : delta[0] }
```

With Ruby 2.5 use [**Object#yield_self**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-yield_self).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548355/ruby-calculate-time-difference-between-2-times) - you should add 24 hours if the difference is negative

```
def time_difference(time_a, time_b)
  difference = time_b - time_a

  if difference > 0
    difference
  else
    24 * 3600 + difference 
  end
end
```

Comment: I copied the exact same *helper* and still getting wrong data as mentioned in the question

Comment: 2015-12-31, 2015-11-31 - it seems to be because you use different months in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> In my application I need to get hour & min from *something* and find its time difference to current UTC time.

*This does not make sense*.

In a computer, time is not "hour & min". Time is a number of seconds since midnight January 1, 1970. Any other view of time to a computer is just window-dressing on top of that. My computer knows that it has been 1,551,120,948 seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970. Since it also understands the Gregorian calendar and time zones, it can display that to me as "2019-02-25 13:55:48 -0500", but it's still just storing a total number of seconds.

So when you say you want to compare "current UTC time" (which is a total number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000) to an "hour & min", I have no idea what you want.

If you consider your example:

> For instance:
>
> ```
> a = Time.parse('2015-12-31 02:00:00 +0100')
> b = Time.parse('2015-11-31 22:00:00 +0100')
> c = time_difference(a, b) / 3600
> ```
>
> would become -676.0 and not 4

Why would the difference be 4 hours? The simplest way I can think to avoid these being different dates is to construct a new time on the same date:

```
b_norm = Time.new(a.year, a.month, a.day, b.hour, b.min, b.sec)
c = time_difference(a, b_norm) / 3600
```

But that gives a time difference of 20 (2AM to 10PM). The only way for it to be a difference of 4 hours is if you interpret b as being *from the previous day*. How do you know to do that?

Your question is simply incomplete as written because an hour and minute need to exist on a particular day to make any sense for doing a calculation.